# Is it possible to copy a binary search tree by only passing a pointer as a parameter?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

For an assignment, I am writing a copy constructor with a helper function.

```
binarytree::binarytree(binarytree& right) {
    copy(root, right.root);
}
```

And my copy function:

```
void binarytree::copy(treenode*& copyRoot, const treenode* root) {  

    if (root != nullptr) {
        //copy data

        //copy left
        copy(copyRoot->left, root->left);

        //copy right
        copy(copyRoot->right, root->right);
}
```

So far, works as intended to make a copy of the BST. However, my assignment specifies that the function will be static, void, and have two treenode* parameters. Is it possible to rewrite this function using `treenode* copyRoot` as a parameter instead of `treenode*& copyRoot`?

If I change the function parameter just as is, the copy of the function is not being saved and is printing out an empty BST when I test.

Comment: No, unless `copyRoot` already points to a valid root node which is modified by the copy function instead of reassigning the pointer. But that is not a good way to implement stuff since the caller of the function always has to create the root node. Are you sure your assignment requires you to pass it by value? That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @FeiXiang `"copy()" should be a static void function with two treenode* parameters` is what the assignment says. I asked my instructor about it, but I think there was some confusion because he specified that the original parameter must be without `&`.

Comment: By Original Parameter I mean the parameter which refers to the original BST which will be copied.

Comment: @dattebane, instructor said that you can't use `&`, but what about pointer to pointer (instead of reference to pointer)? `void change(int** ppInt) { (*ppInt) = new int(7); }` allow to return pointer without `&`. Test code is `int* pInt = nullptr; change(&pInt);`

Comment: Note that what atrelinski mentioned is still not good code. The proper way is a reference like what you're currently using.

Comment: @atrelinski I figured I was missing something because I find pointers infinitely confusing. If a pointer to a pointer is ok, which seems like it wouldn't be a good idea anyways, I would assume using *& is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to rewrite this function using treenode* copyRoot as a parameter instead of treenode*& copyRoot?

I am making assumption that goal of `binarytree::copy()` is to create new copy of  `treenode` (line `copyRoot = new treenode();` suggest it), so for this case...

No, You can't do that.

By `treenode*& copyRoot` argument statement You are "returning" pointer, while `treenode* copyRoot` means that You are passing pointer to `copy()` method and in result inside `copy()` method in fact You have another copy of this pointer.

The best illustration for this case would be `void cpy(int& i)` and `void cpy(int i)` methods. The latter case doesn't change int passed to method. Now replace `int` by `int*` and this should be pretty straight forward explanation for Your question.

Comment: I fail to see how can passing pointers by reference be called *returning* the said pointer... Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: His code is legit. He is passing the ptr be reference so he can pass the new root ptr back to the caller.

Comment: thank you for the basic int example. That makes perfect sense.